# Local files shared between two projects stored in git

Tags: git, share

I am working on two different web sites, each with its own git repository. I have some generic code (PHP and JavaScript) which is common to both sites, and which I keep in a separate `libs` folder on my development machine, using a symlink so that both local web sites believe that this `libs` folder is at the root of the site.

I would like to manage the `libs` folder with git, too. I can imagine two different approaches:

- Two remote copies of the `libs` folder, one in each site repo
- A third git repository, just to manage the `libs` folder, with a way for the two remote site repos to know about the existence of this `libs` repo, so that all is tracked together.

I would appreciate help in deciding which of these two options is more reliable (or if there is an even better option). I would also be grateful for help in understanding how to set up the chosen option.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [git submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) were made for (see also in [Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

`libs` is a separate code entity. It is shared between two (and possibly more) projects and can be versioned on its own. A perfect candidate for a submodule.

**To do in project A:**

1. Remove the symlink and leave files only in project A. ( Git will probably not catch the changes in project B.)
2. [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).
3. Push the new submodule to its own remote. You can use any Git hosting (Bitbucket is good for free closed repos) or a local folder (secure, but vulnerable to moves and renames).

**To do in project B:**

4. Commit the loss of data. `git add -u`, `git commit -m'detached libs'`
5. Add that submodule from remote: `git submodule add <repo-url> [<local path>]`

Now you can check how it works, pushing and pulling from both repos.

Extra questions:

**Why not just clone submodule in B from submodule in A?**
This makes a more independent and flexible structure. What if you will have N projects? What if then you want to delete A? What if you want to move A in your filesystem? The scheme will break.

**Why not just initiate both submodules with `git-subtree`?**
Commit's sha1 depends also on creation time. So the two submodules will have perfectly equal contents (and matching sha1-s for blobs and trees) but completely different history. You will have to merge them, which is extra work.